# How can i merge array of objects with underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs-directive, underscore.js

I have an array of objects like this:

```
array1 = [
  {field: 'username', display: 'username', hide: true},
  {field: 'age', display: 'Age', hide: true},
  {field: 'height', display: 'Height', hide: true}
]
```

Then I have array2:

```
array2 = [
  {field: 'username', display: 'username 123', hide: false},
  {field: 'age', hide: false}
]
```

I want to merge these two arrays by their field i.e. the final result should be:

```
array3 = [
  {field: 'username', display: 'username 123', hide: false},
  {field: 'age', display: 'Age', hide: false},
  {field: 'height', display: 'Height', hide: true}
]
```

I tried `var newObj = _.extend(array1, array2);` but it didn't give me what I want.

Comment: You are looking for concat. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @Brian: nope, he's doing some sort of updating.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Ah yes, he wants to merge the objects as well as the array

Comment: it's not even clear what the order will be if array2 contains new elements... is the order important? if not, go with a plain object (as a dictionary). if it does, an order dictionary would be better for the task. it helps with the lookups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no one function that will do it, as its a fairly specialized operation.  However, its a fairly simple composition of underscore functions:

```
_.values(_.extend(_.indexBy(array1, 'field'), _.indexBy(array2, 'field')))
```

We use `indexBy` to turn the arrays into objects keyed on the `field` value, and then `extend` does what we want.  Finally, `values` turns it back into an array.

Note that while this doesn't make any guarantees about the order, in the current `_` and v8 implementations the final array will be the things from `array1` followed by the things from `array2` that aren't in `array1`, sorted in the original ordering of each array.

Also note that the `_.extend` function is destructive on the first argument, while this doesn't change either array.

If you want to be sure that the order is the same as the original `array1`:

```
order = _.object(_.map(array1, function(obj, i) { return [obj.field, i]; }))
_.sortBy(_.values(_.extend(_.indexBy(array1, 'field'), _.indexBy(array2, 'field'))), function(obj) { order[obj.field]; })
```

Here we make a lookup table of positions and then sort the original solution based on the lookup table.

Comment: thanks , that was what i want. How can i preserve the order . i mean i want that order should stay as of in first array. second array won't have any new elements. its only for updating

Comment: I have 2 list one is : `[{"image_id": 631293, "score": 73}, {"image_id": 11848407, "score": 56}]`

second one is `[{"image_id": 631293, "article_id": 173}, {"image_id": 11848407, "article_id": 121}`

if I try to apply your method, it does not change anything

Comment: @Toucouleur You probably want to replace `'field'` with `'image_id'`, since it looks like that is your key field.

Comment: I am almost 3 years late but this answer is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! :)